# Login page with remote PHP file & MySQL in PhoneGap

Tags: php, jquery, cordova

I am creating an Android app from which a user login is passed to a remote PHP file for login.
I am using JSON. The code is below

```
function loginToWebsite(){
 $.ajax({  
 url: "mywebsite/db.php",
  type: "POST",  
  data: "username=" + $("#emailid").val()+"&password=" + $("#password").val(),
datatype:"json",
  success: function(status)
  {  
    if(status.success == false) 
    {  

        $("#lable")  
            .attr('class', 'ui-state-error')  
            .html('<strong>ERROR</strong>: Your details were incorrect.<br />');  
    } 
    else { 
             $("#lable")  
            .attr('class', 'ui-state-highlight')  
            .html('<strong>PERFECT</strong>: You may proceed. Good times.<br />');  
        }  
  }  

});
```

so I am unable to send the uid & password to the remote php file for execution. Please guide me if their is any error in my code.

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: Is your whish a PHP authentication code?